# Access control (RBAC) with exclusion for REST

Tags: php, rest, acl, rbac, abac

Are there any access control approaches that allow customizing permissions (exclusion of a rule permission for a specific user - for RESTful webservice)?

**Example:**

*Mary has the role of supervisor where she can create and edit posts, however I would like to remove the permission to create posts but keep the role of Mary's supervisor.*

> **User:** Mary
>
> **Role:** supervisor
>
> **Permission:** Create and Edit posts.
>
> **Intented:** Mary is a supervisor and can't create posts.

Note: I don't want create two roles. The system administrator must be able to customize the roles and permissions (pre-defined) of the users. I would be grateful for suggestions of libraries in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a rule-based approach where you could define:

1. A supervisor can create and edit posts
2. Deny a user the right to create if they are on a blacklist.

To do that, look into XACML or ALFA which do just that. I think there is a PHP XACML library